# Create Table SQL query - select table name from string

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable, create-table

I'm attempting to programmatically create a SQL table. I can create a table with a query, this is no issue at all. But I'd like the table name to have some relevance to the data inserted into it, as it's being used for quotations and invoices. Data entered from a DataGridView will be inserted into it (probably via bulkcopy, or something similar).

```
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
                  "CREATE TABLE table1' (Weight INT, Name NVARCHAR, Breed NVARCHAR)", con))
```

works perfectly. However I'd like this code to work:

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf"))
{
   con.Open();
   try
   {
      string tableName = "" + quotenameTxt.Text + "-" +firstTxt.Text+ "-" + surenameTxt.Text;

      using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
         "CREATE TABLE '"+tableName.ToString()+"' (Weight INT, Name NVARCHAR, Breed NVARCHAR)", con))
      {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Any suggestions? I get an error (as expected) but are unsure what I need to do.

> I'm using SqlCe (and before anyone says "BulkCopy isn't supported", I know, I've got a reference that allows it)

The error I get is :

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 16,Token in error = 1-2-3 ]

// "1-2-3" being the textbox values.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Something about incorrect syntax?

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 16,Token in error = 1-2-3 ]  //  "1-2-3" being the textbox values.

Comment: First, debug and check what the value of `string tableName` is.  Second, since `tableName` already _is_ a string, you don't need to call `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: I have it diplayed in a messagebox, as 1-2-3. (Values from textboxes on the form) I've removed `.ToString()` and still get the same error

Comment: It isn't 1-2-3 though.  You have a leading white space when you create the string.

Comment: Change the dashes to underscores or surround the entire table name with [square brackets] .

Comment: Changed to `string tableName =  quotenameTxt.Text + "-" +firstTxt.Text+ "-" + surenameTxt.Text;` and still the same error.

Comment: `string tableName = quotenameTxt.Text + "-" +firstTxt.Text+ "-" + surenameTxt.Text;` - Define it this way.  And change this line to:   `"CREATE TABLE '[" + tableName.ToString()+"]' (Weight INT, Name NVARCHAR, Breed NVARCHAR)", con))`.

Comment: @BateTech think that might of cured it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the dashes to underscores or surround the entire table name with [square brackets]

Comment: `[]` sorted the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in comments above, make the following changes:

```
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
     "CREATE TABLE '"+tableName+"' (Weight INT, Name NVARCHAR, Breed NVARCHAR)", con))
```

`tableName` is already a string.  No need to use `.ToString()` on it.

Also, you have a leading white space in your declaration of `tableName`:

```
string tableName = "" + quotenameTxt.Text + "-" + firstTxt.Text + "-" 
                      + surenameTxt.Text;
```

This makes the string " 1-2-3", not the "1-2-3" you are expecting.

Lastly, surround your `tableName` with `[]` to get it to work correctly:

```
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
   "CREATE TABLE '[" + tableName + "]' (Weight INT, Name NVARCHAR, Breed NVARCHAR)", con))
```

Comment: Excellent description. Makes it easier to understand. Now to find a way of displaying all the tables from a database as a list view, or something similar.